# Resolving deadlock between an UPDATE and a SELECT with query hint

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, hints

I bumped into a page lock deadlock on a table when two queries are running at the same time in two separate sessions, one is selecting from the table (holds S lock on page x and waits for S lock on page y) and one is updating the table (holds IX lock on a page y and waits for IX lock on page x).

The queries are like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A a JOIN Table_B b ON ...
```

and

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE Table_A ...
UPDATE Table_B ...
COMMIT
```

The deadlock happened sometimes on Table_A and sometimes on Table_B. In order to resolve that, I added tablock to the SELECT query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A a WITH (TABLOCK) JOIN Table_B b WITH (TABLOCK) ON ...
```

which solved the page lock deadlock, but I got a new type of deadlock, where the UPDATE holds IX lock on Table_A and waits for IX lock on Table_B, while the SELECT holds S lock on Table_B and waits for S lock on Table_A.

Is there a way to make the SELECT to get BOTH table locks together and wait if either one is not available? Instead of getting one first and wait on the other? Or better, if you can resolve the original page lock deadlock without using WITH (TABLOCK)?

Added steps to reproduce the deadlock:

```
1. CREATE TABLE table_a(id int, value varchar(10))
2. CREATE TABLE table_b(id int, a_id int, value varchar(10))
3. Open a new session
4. Run
    BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE table_a SET value = 'a' WHERE id = 1
5. Open a new session
6. Run
    SELECT * FROM table_a a WITH (TABLOCK) JOIN table_b b WITH (TABLOCK) ON a.id = b.a_id
   notice it is waiting on the first session
7. Go back to the first session
8. Run UPDATE table_b SET value = 'b' WHERE id = 2
9. Wait a few seconds, one of the session will become deadlock victim
```

Comment: The deadlock graph would be primarily helpful here. Also seeing the actual execution plans of both queries would likely be of use too.

Comment: @J.D. I believe this question is general enough, both tables can contain just 1 to 2 columns, really nothing special. Can you help with the locking two tables together part?

Comment: No one will really be able to help you without the deadlock graph unfortunately. It doesn't really matter how simple the queries / table design is, it comes down to how they executed in that moment which is based on a multitude of factors that can't be speculated on.

Comment: If you turned on READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT then the SELECT wouldn't need S locks. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @J.D. I mean the deadlock is totally reproducible: starts two sessions, runs BEGIN TRAN and UPDATE Table_A in one session, runs the SELECT in another session, runs UPDATE Table_B in the first session, you get the deadlock.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thank you, I tried that but it ran 3 times slower. If there is no better way I will use that.

Comment: @user1589188 That's fine and all, except I can run the exact same query that you provide (even identically written verbatim) on my SQL Server instance and still end up with a different outcome. So it doesn't matter how much you trivialize it, an exact answer to your situation is not possible without the information I requested. Just general suggestions for potential improvement can be made, such as David's instead. To my point, RCSI shouldn't necessarily make your query slower. Also, the generic example you gave in your last comment wouldn't even cause a deadlock under normal circumstances.

Comment: @J.D. Updated to include steps to reproduce the deadlock

Comment: "it ran 3 times slower" 3 times slower than what?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft than without

Comment: What was the absolute difference in duration?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft the whole process ran from 5min to 15min after turning on READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT (although this resolved the occasion deadlock)